# How do I use poisons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am concentrating in alchemy in order to use poisons with my attacks. I have made several bottles, but I am unsure how to use them. I am a bit worried about 'using' them in my inventory in case my character just drinks it himself.

Can I apply it to weapons, and will it work with a bow?

Comment: when dual wielding you can poison both weapons, so long as you use a different poison for each weapon

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can only apply a poison to an equipped weapon: it'll tell you that if you try to use it without having a weapon equipped.

And you can only apply poison to one of your weapons: if you try to re-apply a poison after applying it to one weapon, it'll say you can't do it. However if you un-equip the weapon in your right hand and equip the weapon that is in your left hand to the right you can then poison it and then equip both weapons with poison.

You can, in fact, poison bows. Just make sure to equip it before applying the poison. This affects the first arrow shot through the bow: after one shot, the poison on the bow goes away. As a corollary to this, you *can't* poison arrows: Skyrim will complain that you don't have a weapon equipped if you try to use a poison with just arrows equipped.

And as [BeatMe notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35922/how-do-i-use-poisons/35928#35928), with the *Poisoned* perk, you can reverse pickpocket marks to poison them stealthily. As long as the pickpocket is successful, this doesn't aggro the mark; in many cases, it'll outright kill them.

Comment: How about throwables? Does it apply to the whole stack or just the first one thrown? Same question with arrows.

Comment: I don't have the game, so I don't know if there are any. But it would be interesting to know if it applied to them.

Comment: @Bora Considering throwing weapons are not in the game, I would say it's a safe bet that the answer is "no" by default. :)

Comment: @MarkTrapp any idea on the effects on dual wielded weapons?

Comment: @theorise I mention that in my answer: only one weapon can be poisoned; it'll prevent you from using poison on the other (complaining that the weapon has already been poisoned).

Comment: if you equip and poison each weapon separately, you can have any poison you want on both weapons

Comment: Can you apply poison to bound (conjured) weapons?

Answer (score 10):

- You can use those poisons from your inventory to apply it to your currently equipped weapons.
- With a pickpocket skill of 40 you can learn the perk *Poisoned* and poison enemys directly by placing potions in their pockets.

Comment: No, they don't notice it. But if your target dies you'll be persecuted. A real stealth kill in puplic is not possible AFAIK (I tried several ways to kill a target, but it wasn't totally stealthy).

Comment: If your poison takes a long time (i.e. any lingering poison) and you walk far enough away and remain invisible, it is possible to do a stealth kill in public.

Answer (score 2):

You just equip the weapon and then press A on the poison that you want to be applied to that weapon.

Answer (score 1):

Drinking it wont poison yourself, it will give you the option to use it on your weapon, or not use it at all. A poison can go on any weapon, even bows.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your item menu go to  your weapons select your wepon go to your potions select a poison and there you go.