# How many hits do poisons last for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When you apply a poison to a weapon, how many hits does it last for?

Does it also wear out if you miss an attack?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Poisons last for a single hit (without the Concentrated Poison perk in the alchemy tree, which doubles the number of hits).

With a melee weapon, if you miss entirely, the application is not used up.  With a bow, the poison is applied to the next shot and is consumed regardless of whether or not you hit.

Comment: Not this is [also true for arrows shot through a poisoned bow](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35922/how-do-i-use-poisons/35925#35925): one arrow shot (hit or miss) and the bow loses its poison.

Comment: Thanks guys, perfect answer. Leads me onto a new question you may be able to answer for me: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36314/do-poison-effects-stack