# Do poison effects stack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I use the same poison on a single target twice, do the effects stack?

For example I hit someone twice with a poison that does `1 damage per second for 10 seconds`, what are the results:

- `2 damage per second for 10 seconds`
- `1 damage per second for 20 seconds`
- `2 damage per second for 20 seconds`
- The timer resets back to 10 seconds on the last hit
- The second poison is ignored

This also leads to the question that if I use the `Concentrated Poison` perk in the `Alchemy` skill tree, are the effects the same as if I used two of the same poison in a row?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lingering damage health does indeed stack.  I tested this by giving multiple lingering poisons to an NPC via the poisoner perk.  Her health went down noticeably faster when I gave her multiple doses.  I do not know how the duration is affected as she died before the poison ran out.  I will report back later after I have found a suitably healthy target.

After some testing, here is what I found out:

- All the potion effects are applied simulatenously.  So if you have a poison that does 2 damage for 20 seconds and one that does 1 damage for 10 seconds, for the first 10 seconds, the target will take  3 damage per second, and for the next 10 seconds, he will take 2 damage per second.  The end result will be 50 damage.
- The same poison will stack with each other, 2 poisons of 1 damage per second for 10 seconds will do 20 damage in total over 10 seconds.
- The reason why some people think they won't stack is if you give an entire stack of poison to the target at one time (any amount >= 6), only the first poison in the stack will trigger.  The rest will be given to the NPC and sit in their inventory as a potion that they now can use.  If you want all the poison effects to trigger, you have to give it one at at time (and risk the 10% chance of detection at each attempt.)

> This also leads to the question that if I use the Concentrated Poison perk in the Alchemy skill tree, are the effects the same as if I used two of the same poison in a row?

This is correct.

Comment: You may have better luck trying to acquire a suitably weak poison instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to IGN, only the time will stack.  I think that a certain perk may also increase the damage as well.

Comment: Hmm... I was under the impression that in Oblivion, each effect was just executed in parallel of eachother. So, not?

Comment: @Konerak I was also under the impression that is how Oblivion worked so I don't see why they wouldn't design Skyrim that way. 
                                                             Angelo, it would be helpful if you gave us a link to where IGN reported that.